# Compiles easily but has run-time errors

Tags: c++, literals

The following program compiles easily but does not do what is given within `if` and `else if` statements. Please tell me where I am making mistakes. I'm a brand new to c++.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <time.h>

using namespace std;
int random(int min, int max) //range : [min, max)
{
   static bool first = true;
   if ( first ) 
   {  

      srand(time(NULL)); //seeding for the first time only!
      first = false;
   }
   return min + rand() % (max - min);
}
class size{
    public:
    int medium;
    int large;
    int small;
};
int main(){
    int min=1000,max=9999;
    int product,ran=random(min,max);
    ofstream myfile ("orders.html");
size fresh;
cout<<"******************************************************************************\n";
cout<<"*                        Fresh fruit juicees                             *\n";
cout<<"******************************************************************************\n";
cout<<"01001. Large mango juice\n";
cout<<"01002. Medium mango juice\n";
cout<<"01003. Small mango juice\n"<<"Enter the product key given before the product name\n";
cin>>product;

if (product==01001){
    cout<<"Thanks for choosing Large one ";
    if (myfile.is_open()){
    myfile<<"<html><head><title>Oreders</title>\n"<<
    "</head><body>Order number "<<ran<<"is pending";
    myfile.close();
}}
    else if(product==01002)
    {
      cout<<"Thanks for choosing medium one";
      myfile<<"<html><head><title>Oreders</title>\n"<<
    "</head><body>Order number "<<ran<<"is pending";
    myfile.close();
}


}
//.....program continues so on;
```

Comment: 01001 (octal) is not the same as 1001 (decimal) - please consider string based comparison.

Comment: Also be aware that "return min + rand() % (max - min);}" may not return an even distribution. Imagine rand() returned a value 0 to 150 and max - min was 100. You'd get inputs of 0.99 producing 0.99 and inputs 100-150 producing 0..50 so not the uniform distribution you might expect....

Answer (score 3):

These are octal literals: `01001`, `01002`, not decimal. They will be interpreted as if they were `513` and `514` in a decimal base system during compilation.

When you read a number that starts with `0` with `cin >> product;`, it treats the input numbers as decimal, unless you add `std::oct` modifier.

Maybe you should use `std::string` for these identifiers instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `int product` to `string product` and then use string comparison. Your "0" prefix will cause the number literals to be interpreted as octal (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal)

Answer (score 0):

It's funny miskate.

If a number begins with zero `0`, the number is supposed to be in octal representation.

For example `01001` (octal) is `513` (decimal).